# Locale.getLanguage() not updating after refreshing UI ( Language Change )

Tags: java, android, translation

I'm changing the language from English to Arabic  programmatically using this function :

```
private void setLocale(String lang) {
        Locale myLocale = new Locale(lang);
        Resources res = getContext().getResources();
        DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        conf.locale = myLocale;
        conf.setLocale(new Locale(lang));
        Locale.setDefault(myLocale);
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
        Intent refresh = new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class);
        getActivity().finish();
        startActivity(refresh);

    }
```

The language is changing,however when using
`Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();`
or
`Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().locale.getLanguage();`
I'm still getting English ( en ) instead of the expected value ar although the displayed language is arabic.
Any idea why it's still returning en?

Answer (score 0):

The configuration is overwritten whenever you go through onCreate(), and a few other calls by the system. So you would need to save the locale in the SharedPreferences & set it in every onCreate() method of every activity.

See here for possible ways:
[Change app language programmatically in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-app-language-programmatically-in-android?rq=1)